# Trying to run VS load test in Azure with Selenium Chrome driver and receive error

Tags: azure, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, load-testing

When I run Load test locally - it works. It opens Chrome and makes actions, clicks and whatever.
But when I run test Online in Azure, it returns error:

*Initialization method SeleniumWebLoadPoc.SelenumLoadWeb.SetupTest threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64).*

I added Chrome driver to deploy in test settings:
[Test settings deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b74I.png)

Did exactly how it's written in Microsoft guide:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/16/using-selenium-with-cloud-based-load-testing/

How can I resolve that issue? Someone already did load tests in Azure with Selenium Web Driver?

Answer (score -1):

I think they don't support ChromeDriver only PhantomJsDriver which makes sense.
This is from their code examples:

```
 _driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

Most probably the user interactions on the test agents is turned off as well.